# Parse error: syntax error in mysqli_fetch_array()

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/u844411171/public_html/index.php on line 8

I have a problem with mysqli_fetch_array(). I use mysqli_fetch_array():

```
if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
$query = "SELECT typ FROM `uzivatel` WHERE id = " . $_SESSION["user_id"];
$uzivatel = $mysqli->query($query);
$prava = mysqli_fetch_array($uzivatel)[0];
}
```

and

```
$celkemClenu = "SELECT count(`id`) FROM 
        `uzivatel`" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($mysqli));
$result = $mysqli->query($celkemClenu);
echo "<p>Celkem členů: " . mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
```

Plz, where is a problem?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks. use `bind_param`.

Comment: You cannot use `or` in the middle of  a variable declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP is [older than 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), which is when direct array dereferencing of function returns was added:

```
echo foo()[0]; // ok in 5.4, syntax error in older versions
```

Workaround, use a temporary variable to store the array:

```
$temp = foo();
echo $temp[0];
```